# How do I allocate writable memory in ARM64 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, arm, ld, arm64

I'm trying to learn ARM64. I'm assembling on the Apple M1.

I'm trying to allocate memory I can write to. I keep receiving the following error:

```
ld: Absolute addressing not allowed in arm64 code but used in '_main' referencing 'foo'
```

My program is very simple:

```
// foo.s
.global _main
.align 2

_main:
  ldr x0, =foo

.data
foo: .zero 8
```

I'm using this script to compile it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

as foo.s -o foo.o &&                               \
                                                   \
ld foo.o -o foo                                    \
   -arch arm64                                     \
   -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` \
   -lSystem
```

After some googling, I tried setting `-no_pie` for ld but that results in:

```
ld: warning: -no_pie ignored for arm64
```

I'm not really sure what's going on.

Thanks

**Update:** There's a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351533/apple-clang12-llvm-unknown-aarch64-fixup-kind) that explains the problem.

I applied that fix and wrote this quick program to test that it works:

```
.global _main
.align 2

_main:
  // Set x0 to the memory address of foo.
  adrp x0, foo@PAGE
  add x0, x0, foo@PAGEOFF

  // Store 123 in foo.
  mov x1, 123
  str x1, [x0]

  // Load the contents of foo into x2.
  ldr x2, [x0]

  // Exit with a status code set to foo.
  mov x0, x2
  mov x16, 1
  svc 0

.data
foo: .zero 8
```

It returns with an exit status of 123 as I'd expect.

Comment: And don't forget `.text` before you start defining `_main`.  It may be the default, but it will save you from breakage if you decide to move your data to the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, the answer to that other SO question has done the trick! I'll be sure to add a `.text` to my program as you suggest!

Answer (score 1):

You allocated the memory just fine with `.zero` in the `.data` section.  Now you just need to load its address in order to access it.

It's better to write position-independent code than to try to disable it.  So instead of trying to load absolute addresses, access them relative to the program counter.

In a program of moderate size (less than a megabyte or so of code plus static data), you can load the address of `foo` into `x0` with

```
adr x0, foo
```

The `adr` instruction adds an immediate constant to the value of the program counter `pc`, and leaves the result in the destination register.  The assembler and linker can determine the difference between the address of the `adr` instruction and the address of `foo`, and encode that difference as the immediate of the `adr` instruction.

For larger programs, in which the difference in addresses may be up to 4 GB or so, you use a combination of `adrp` to get the high bits, and `add` or a load/store with offset.  See [What are the semantics of ADRP and ADRL instructions in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly)

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's really helpful. However, when I make that change I then get this error:  'foo.s:5:3: error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!'. It's as though it can't find that label name anymore?

Comment: Oh, it appears from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351533/apple-clang12-llvm-unknown-aarch64-fixup-kind that on MacOS you have to use the "larger program" technique with `adrp` in all cases.  I think that question may be a duplicate of yours.

Comment: Thanks, that other SO post has worked.